# How do I calculate the right ascension of the points along the ecliptic at given elevations?

Tags: astronomy, planets, geometry

How do I calculate the right ascension of the point along the ecliptic nearest the sun at sunset and sunrise that is at a given altitude/elevation?

For example, I'd like to compute the right ascension at sunrise of the point westward along the ecliptic that is at an altitude/elevation of 10°, given the date and time of a sunrise. In general, I assume, this is the same as calculating western/eastern most the RA's of a points along elliptic at a given altitude/elevation at a specified time. This seems like it should be a family straightforward exercise in spherical trigonometry; but that art is lost to me.

Comment: I think that if you attempted (and included) a 3D sketch of what you are trying to do, we can help you with the spherical trig; but I for one cannot figure out what you are asking from the description alone.

Comment: I'll try. But if I could draw it I think I could solve it. In the meantime: At the time the sun sets, t, working eastwards along the ecliptic, how far do you have to go (i.e., what is the RA) of the point that is X degrees above the horizon? Ho do you calculate RA given X and t?

Comment: There are several ascension calculators easily found via a Google search.  Two examples: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/azel.html  and http://www.sunearthtools.com/dp/tools/pos_sun.php .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I've got solar position. What I have is time and a desired elevation; what I'm looking for is is the function used to calculate the point along the ecliptic at that elevation at that time.

Comment: mmm. you sure you can't back that out of the dataset these calculators provide?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Not sure. But what I've got is $t$ and $X$. In fact lots of $t$s; hundreds or even thousands. So I'm looking for an *algorithm*. I also have most other basic ephemerides (rise, set, transit, etc.; and can do coordinate transforms relatively easily); but what I need is to know what the formula is; or how to extract $RA(X, t)$ ultimately from the ephemerides I have, even if indirectly as $RA(f(X), g(t))$ where $g$ and $f$ are some ephemerides.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, the diagram looks like this:

[image]

Where I am drawing on the unit sphere, so distances $a$ and $b$ scale from 0 to $2\pi$.

The sine rule for spherical triangles is

$$\frac{\sin{A}}{\sin{a}}=\frac{\sin{B}}{\sin{b}}$$

Now since $B=90°$, it follows that

$$a = \sin^{-1}(\sin{A} \sin{b})$$

Please see whether that makes sense for your case - using a few known examples and the online calculators referenced in the comments above.

Comment: Where do those lines meet? At the sphere's center or at the horizon? In any case I don't have $A$ (at least not readily). But the diagram is helpful: given $a$ relative to the horizon (celestial elevation) and a time (which ultimately gives $A$, but I'm not sure of the calculation — that's a part of the solution I'm looking for, perhaps), I'm looking for $b$ (or better, $b$ measured from a fixed reverence, such as 0 RA).